# How can I show tasks only of current virtual desktop in Ubuntu dock?

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, ubuntu-dock, dock

Is there way I can only show the tasks which are running in the Ubuntu dock which are running on the current virtual desktop instead of showing all the tasks?

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.